# How to obtain a dataframe where cols and rows come from column's values of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with the following structure:

```
my_df

date        hour  product
2019-06-06  17    laptopt
2019-06-06  15    printer
2019-06-07  14    laptopt
2019-06-07  17    desktop
```

How can I get a df like this:

```
hour  laptop  printer  desktop
14    1       0        0
15    0       1        0
16    0       0        0 
17    1       0        1
```

So far I've been trying doing `my_df.groupby(["product","hour"]).count().unstack(level=0)`

```
        date
product desktop laptop  printer
hour            
14      NaN     1.0     NaN
15      NaN     NaN     1.0
17      1.0     1.0     NaN
```

and I'm stucked there.

Thanks.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Call what you already have `unstacked` and do this:

```
index = pd.RangeIndex(df.hour.min(),df.hour.max() + 1)
unstacked.reindex(index).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.crosstab` and `reindex`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['hour'], df['product'])
   .reindex(pd.RangeIndex(df['hour'].min(), df['hour'].max()+1), fill_value=0))

product  desktop  laptopt  printer
14             0        1        0
15             0        0        1
16             0        0        0
17             1        1        0
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.set_index('hour')['product'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reindex(range(df.hour.min(),df.hour.max()+1),fill_value=0)
Out[15]: 
      desktop  laptopt  printer
hour                           
14          0        1        0
15          0        0        1
16          0        0        0
17          1        1        0
```